# Is 如果我们，所有的学生，没有我们的中文老师，我们就永远不能站起来在听众前面说中文 grammatical and does it makes sense?

Tags: grammar, spoken, writing-critique

English:

> If we, all the students, never had our teachers, we would never be able to stand and speak Chinese in front of an audience.

My variation in Chinese:

> 如果我们，所有的学生，没有我们的中文老师，我们就永远不能站起来在听众前面说中文。

I want to know if this sentence is correctly translated and makes sense in terms of Chinese grammar.

P.S. This is for a spoken performance in a competition. I would also like to know if I can actually say it like this.

Comment: 如果，像我们这样所有的学生从来没有我们的老师，我们永远不可能站在听众前说汉语。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "如果我们，[*所有的学生*]，没有[*我们的中文*]老师，我们就[*永远*]不能站[*起来*]在听众前面说中文。"
>
> [ ] parts can be omitted.

Subject and object can often be omitted to make the speech flow smoother.

- The first 我们 already indicated 'all the students' therefore '所有的学生' is not needed.
- No need to state it is 'our Chinese language teachers' (我们的中文老师) just '老师' is enough, we know whose teachers they are and what subject they teach from the context.
- *永远* is not needed, the phrase 'if there's no teachers, we can't...' already indicated 'never'
- 不能站[*起来*]在听众前面说中文。"  = "stand up and speak Chinese in front of the audience" can be reduced to "stand in front of the audience and speak Chinese"
- 面前 is better than 前面 for 'in front of' when you mean 'facing' ; *'站在听众前面' could mean you are facing the same direction with the audience*

It would make your speech more native sounding:

> "如果没有老师，我们就不能站在听众面前说中文(了)。"
>
> The first  '我们' can be omitted because the subject is clearly indicated in the following sentence. We don't need to repeat the subject in the same context.
>
> (add final particle '了' to make the sentence sound complete)

*To construct a fluent sentence, you should look for anything that can be omitted, as long as the meaning remain unchanged.*

Answer (score 3):

> 如果没有老师，我们——所有学生——就绝不可能在听众面前说中文。

I think that "all the students" must be translated and not omitted; here it is used for emphasis.  And "would never be able to " is 绝不可能。

Answer (score 2):

Actually we should consider re-arranging the structure of the sentence, and remove some redundant emphasizing expressions, to conform it naturally to Chinese speaking habit, a.e.

Change:

> If we, all the students, never had our teachers, we would never be
>   able to stand and speak Chinese in front of an audience.

To:

> Had it not been our Chinese teachers, we all the students would never be able to stand and speak Chinese in front of an audience.

**如果不是因为我们的中文老师，我们这些学生是不可能站在观众面前说中文的。**

Note the expression "**would never be able to**" is translated into "**不可能**" in favor of "永远不能" as the original sentence is to stress on the **impossibility** rather than the infinity of time. Also, "**all the students**" is translated into "**这些**学生" instead of "所有学生" to avoid it from racing against "不可能", which is the main stress of the sentence.